# Flink: Multi-data center deployment possible?

Tags: apache-flink

Does Flink support multi-data center deployments so that jobs can survive a single data-center outage (i.e. resume failed jobs in a different data-center) ?

My limited research on Google suggests the answer: there is no such support.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While there is no explicit support for multi-datacenter failover in Flink, it can be (and has been) setup. A Flink Forward talk provides one example: engineers from Uber describe their experience with this and related topics in [Practical Experience running Flink in Production](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBrjgU-sjwM). There are a number of components to their solution, but the key ideas are: (1) running extra YARN resource managers, configured with a longer inetaddr.ttl, and (2) checkpointing to a federation of two HDFS clusters.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26574639)

Comment: @thatguy I've expanded my answer a bit.